# Pi Zero OTG ethernet zero with USB-C

Tags: otg

I have been doing a series of projects using RPiZs networked using ethernet over USB. In the middle of this, I upgraded my computer to a new MacBook Pro which only has USB-C ports, so now I need to use an adapter. I cannot connect via USB anymore through the adapter.

Is it possible to connect a macbrook pro with USB-C ports to a raspberry pi zero as an ethernet gadget?

Comment: Help us out with some more info, please: Did you use macOS before the upgrade? which version? What type of adapter? Did you run `ifconfig` before & after plugging in the PiZ? My **suspicion** is that it has more to do with Apple's "security" than it does w/ the adapter itself, but let's find out.

Comment: Of top of head this should not be an issue - you will have to check the Mac has set up a new RNDIS device in sys pref / network and if so set the MAC addresses and gateway by hand (they can be random - thanks Apple).  Sometimes you may have to `sudo nano/etc/modprobe.d/g_ether.conf`
and put this at the end options g_ether use_eem=0 on the Pi and then reboot.

Comment: I do not see the problem with Raspberry Pi. As far as I know it has a micro USB connector. If so just use a cheep micro usb to USB C adapter and everything is done. Am I wrong?